# Loop through multiple values in Set-Header policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Wondering if there's a way to loop through all values for a particular header and modify each one. I have the need to do a string replace on each value of a header and I want to avoid assuming how many values for that header there will be. I do not see a way to create a loop in API Management policies.

```html
 <outbound>
      <base />
      <choose>
          <when condition="@(context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Set-Cookie"))">
              <set-header name="Set-Cookie" exists-action="override">
                  <value - How can I loop through these?>@{
                      var currentHeader = context.Response.Headers["Set-Cookie"][i];
                      //perform necessary string.replace
                  }</value>
              </set-header>
          </when>
      </choose>
  </outbound>
```

Comment: See the Collection of Things Section of the blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2017/09/25/deep-dive-on-set-body-policy/

Comment: Yes. There isn't any policy to create a loop in APIM and you can't update headers from a policy expression either. Its probably best to open a feature request on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management) for this.